# Finding the indexes of all occurrences of an element in a vector

Tags: c++, vector

Suppose I have a vector `A = {1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0}`. Now I want to get the indexes of all occurrences of 0 returned as another vector `B`.

```
template< class InputIt, class T>
std::vector<int> IndicesOf(InputIt first, InputIt last, const T& value) {

}
```

Here is a start:

```
std::vector<int>::iterator iter = std::find_if(A.begin(), A.end(), 0);
B = std::distance(A.begin(), iter);
```

Comment: @ScottMorken shouldn't that be `template <class InputIt, class T> std::vector<size_t> ...`? OP was looking for a set of indices, not a set of copies of elements.

Comment: yes you are right, edited again

Answer (score 27):

Just call `std::find_if` again, with the previously returned iterator (plus one) as the beginning. Do in a loop until `std::find_if` returns `A.end()`.

---

Sample code

```
#include <algorithm> //find_if

bool isZero(int x){
    return x == 0;
}

std::vector<int>::iterator iter = A.begin();
while ((iter = std::find_if(iter, A.end(), isZero)) != A.end())
{
    // Do something with iter

    iter++;
}
```

Comment: can you please explain in more detail i did not get.

Comment: Thanks, I made it                                       std::vector<int>::iterator iter = data.begin();
while ((iter = std::find(iter, data.end(), 0)) != data.end())
{
   int idx = std::distance(data.begin(), iter);
  cout<<idx;
    iter++;
}

Comment: @stephanmg No there's nothing specific to C++11 (or higher) in my answer.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Oh, yes, I skimmed over too quickly.

Answer (score 4):

To the answer of @some-programmer-dude with lamda:

```
#include <algorithm> //find_if

std::vector<int> A{1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0};
std::vector<int> B;

std::vector<int>::iterator it = A.begin();
while ((it = std::find_if(it, A.end(), [](int x){return x == 0; })) != A.end())
{
    B.push_back(std::distance(A.begin(), it));
    it++;
}
```

Comment: Small typo: your semicolon should be outside the parentheses, i.e.:

    B.push_back(std::distance(A.begin(), it));

Comment: @ProfessorNuke You're absolutely right. Thanks. I just fixed it.

Comment: Thanks. What if you need the lambda to compare against a variable rather than literal zero? Ie, before the while loop I have testval = 5. How do we pass and test x against testval with the lambda?

Comment: @AndrewTruckle You would use a lambda capture. `[capture] (arguments) {code body}`. If it is only this var, you can just do `[&testval](int x){return x == testval; }`, I think. See here for more info: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda

Answer (score 2):

Try this:
char c: element whose indexes you want to get.
I used a string but this same code will work perfectly fine with a vector.
vecky stores all the indexes found.

```
std::vector<int> getIndex(string s, char c)
{
    std::vector<int> vecky;

    for (int i = 0; i != s.length(); i++)
    {
        if (s[i] == c)
        {
            vecky.push_back(i);
        }
    }

    return vecky;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution is a bit longer if you consider `#include`s and `using`s, but that is irrelevant in bigger code bases.

Without those, and considering that one could store some useful function object like `first` and `second` in a header, the core part becomes a one liner:

```cpp
auto result = enumerate(v) | filter(second_is_zero) | transform(first);
```

Defining `second_is_zero` is a bit overkill; defining `auto constexpr equal_to = std::equal_to<>{};` instead, would lead to the following, which is still readable, once you get used to functional utilities such as `compose` and `partial`:

```cpp
auto result = enumerate(v) | filter(compose(partial(equal_to, 0), second))
                           | transform(first);
```

Here's the complete code, though

```cpp
#include <boost/hana/functional/compose.hpp>
#include <boost/hana/functional/partial.hpp>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <range/v3/view/enumerate.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/filter.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/transform.hpp>

using boost::hana::compose;
using boost::hana::partial;
using namespace ranges::views;

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> v{1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0};

  // define some useful function object
  auto constexpr first = [](auto const& pair){ return pair.first; };
  auto constexpr second = [](auto const& pair){ return pair.second; };
  auto constexpr second_is_zero = compose(partial(std::equal_to<>{},0), second);

  // oneline to get the result (it's in a view, not a vector)
  auto result = enumerate(v)           // attach indexes 0,1,2,... to the elements
              | filter(second_is_zero) // filter based on second
              | transform(first);      // extract the indexes

  // the following prints 14568
  for (auto i : result) {
    std::cout << i;
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```