# How to find all positions of an element using std::find?

Tags: c++, search, vector, find

I am using the following code to find a string in a `std::vector` of `std::string`. But how to return all the positions of a particular element?

I simply use `std::find`, but I can only return the first position.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<string> vec;
    vector<string>::iterator it;

    vec.push_back("a");
    vec.push_back("i");
    vec.push_back("g");
    vec.push_back("h");
    vec.push_back("l");
    vec.push_back("a");
    vec.push_back("n");
    vec.push_back("d");
    vec.push_back("e");
    vec.push_back("r");

    it=find(vec.begin(),vec.end(),"a");
    int pos = distance(vec.begin(), it);

    if(it!=vec.end()){
        cout<<"FOUND AT : "<<pos<<endl;
    }
    else{
        cout<<"NOT FOUND"<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I could only get 0, how can I get 5 also?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding the indexes of all occurrences of an element in a vector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25846235/finding-the-indexes-of-all-occurrences-of-an-element-in-a-vector)

Comment: std::find(it+1, vec.end(), "a")?

Answer (score 3):

> I simply use `std::find`, but I can only return the first position.

Because you always start your search at the beginning of the container.

But `std::find` can search *any* range, not just a complete container; so instead, just start each new search **where the last one stopped**.

Here is an example based on your existing code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> vec;

    vec.push_back("a");
    vec.push_back("i");
    vec.push_back("g");
    vec.push_back("h");
    vec.push_back("l");
    vec.push_back("a");
    vec.push_back("n");
    vec.push_back("d");
    vec.push_back("e");
    vec.push_back("r");

    bool found_at_least_once = false;
    auto start_it = begin(vec);
    while (start_it != end(vec)) {
        start_it = std::find(start_it, end(vec), "a");
        if (start_it != end(vec)) {
            auto const pos = std::distance(begin(vec), start_it);
            std::cout << "FOUND AT : " << pos << '\n';
            ++start_it;
            found_at_least_once = true;
        }
    }

    if (!found_at_least_once) {
        std::cout << "NOT FOUND" << '\n';
    }
}
```

Observations on this specific program:

- `start_it` is the iterator where every search starts. It is initially `begin(vec)`.
- The loop continues as long as `start_it` has not arrived at `end(vec)`.
- If the vector is empty (`begin(vec) == end(vec)`), then the loop is never entered at all.
- `std::find` returns an iterator the the found element or to `end(vec)`.
- If the element is not found, then the loop will end because `start_it` will be `end(vec)`.
- If it is found, then the next loop iteration will start the `std::find` search **one element past the** last result because of the `++start_it;` line.
- Because you will eventually arrive at `end(vec)` anyway, you need to explicitly remember if at least one search was successful, hence the boolean variable. That's because you want special handling for the case when nothing is found. If the goal was instead to simply print nothing if `"a"` is never found, then you would not need the boolean variable.

General coding-style observations:

- `auto` is a great way to remove the need for spelling out complicated type declarations without sacrificing type safety.
- Prefer the non-member functions `begin` and `end` to the member functions.
- Do not use `using namespace std;`.
- Include `<string>` if you use `std::string`, or else your code is platform-dependent for no good reason at all.
- Use `'\n'` instead of `std::endl`.

---

Personally, I don't think a `std::find`/`std::distance`-based solution is a very good idea here. For the sake of code clarity, I'd probably use a plain old `for` loop like this:

```
bool found_at_least_once = false;
for (std::vector<std::string>::size_type pos = 0; pos < vec.size(); ++pos) {
    if (vec[pos] == "a") {
        std::cout << "FOUND AT : " << pos << '\n';
        found_at_least_once = true;
    }
}
```

Note that `vec.size()` can and should be replaced by `size(vec)` in C++17.

Comment: wanted to comment on your first version that the do{} while() looks a bit strange and isn't needed but you fixed it already :]

Answer (score -2):

this code works for me:

Edit: sorry didn't read the question carefully. ;)

Edit: thanks for the feedback, this is warning-removed my code!

```
auto begin = vec.begin();
unsigned int pos = 0;
while (true)
{
  auto result = find(begin, vec.end(), "a");
  if (result == vec.end())      break;
  else
  {
    if(result == begin)  printf("pos: %d\n", pos);
    ++begin;
    ++pos;
  }
}
```

Comment: You've to explain your code, not just copy-paste it!

Comment: This does not answer the question asked. OP wants to get positions of **both** `"a"` elements, your code can only detect one.

Comment: Looks suspicious.. did you test this? There's a comparision between ptr_diff_t and size_t which will cause compiler warnings (with reason), furthermore  begin is an iterator to a vector of std::string but you are dereferencing it then assiging a ptr_diff_t to it. In other words, you are modifying the strings in the input vector in a strange way. One of the reasons any find algorythm should ususally use const iterators. Anyway, refer to the sample code in the linked question: it already has a solution and it's better than this one.

Comment: @stijn, i removed warning message, and more simpler!